# content script heavy calculation causes poor performance (chrome extension)

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a simple chrome extension, and I'm trying to do some page analysis through the content.js. this is the code:

```
console.log("content.js running.."); //debug

    var fromDOM = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document);
    console.log(fromDOM)
    var i = 0;
    var item;

    for (item in fromDOM) {
        var x = fromDOM[item];
        if (x == "/"){
            i++;
            console.log(i);
            chrome.runtime.sendMessage({lala: i});
        }

    }
```

This code searches for any occurence of "/" in the page and sends a message to a background script (that currently does nothing).

This for loop alone causes any tab I load to load slower than usual.. affecting user performance.

What am I doing wrong here? I can't do heavy lifting on content.js scripts? or is there a better way I'm missing.

Comment: XMLSerializer is used to also see html tags correct me If i'm wrong but using your way it only gets javascript

Comment: As for TreeWalker - never heard of it, are you saying its more efficient?

Comment: The actual goal is really general because I'm planning on checking for js, specific tags, tags and attributes, etc. so im intentionally including all this for functionality (i hope at least) - im just confused about the most efficient way

Comment: Okay, it seems you know what you're doing :-) let me see if I can make a faster code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to process the current HTML of the page:

1. Use `document.documentElement.innerHTML`
2. Use string methods like `indexOf` to get the position of each `/` without enumerating the long HTML string character by character.
3. Accumulate all the positions in an array and send it in one message since sending of a message is an expensive operation that involves internal JSON.stringify+JSON.parse.
4. Don't use `console.log` when devtools is open as it does a lot of extra processing to format the messages. And generally prefer debugging interactively - there's a panel in devtools to inspect and set breakpoints in content scripts so you can debug the code, view the variables, and so on.

```js
const html = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
const slashes = [];

let pos = -1;
do {
  pos = html.indexOf('/', pos + 1);
  if (pos >= 0) {
    slashes.push(pos);
  }
} while (pos >= 0);

chrome.runtime.sendMessage({lala: slashes});
```

Now your background listener will receive an array of character positions - not really useful per se, but that's just an example. You can put more info inside the array to make it more meaningful.